# Short story about bug-like aliens invading/destroying Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story around 10 years ago, probably between 2010-2012. The main plot was these bug-like (praying mantis?) aliens were taking over the Earth. The protagonist had a small group of friends/family that I think tried to fight in the beginning, but realized they couldn't win.

They eventually had to retreat to their underground lab/bunker, that was set up to preserve/repopulate the human race. I remember specifically the protagonist was a young man and he was Polish, as he talked about using a Western version of his Polish name.

I can't remember if it was a stand alone short story or part of a collection, but I believe it was an ebook.

Comment: Sounds familiar.  This one's gonna bug me.

Comment: Bug aliens and Polish roots of the main character sound like _Ender's Game_ series.